# Disable Password List suggestion pick in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, autocomplete

*In html code i have try to use this:*

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new">
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="nope">
```

Update test diferent name tag:

```
<input type="password" name="p1" autocomplete="nope">
<input type="password" name="p2" autocomplete="nope">
<input type="password" name="ahgsfkhas" autocomplete="nope">
```

*To prevent chrome to show suggestion picker List, but none of this work, this is the result:*

[image]

***some way to disable this through an HTML or JQuery / javascript tag, I don't have access to all Chrome installations on PCs, like to edit this feature***

***this is not an offer to save password; this is a select picker from password stored (Password Manager). this breaks into the Interface of a Web Page, and I see no way to deactivate it from the web page, since I don't have access to the browser settings.***

Comment: I saw that the suggestions depended on the name of the input, try a random name to see

Comment: @clota974 same result.. with diferent names

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem it seems difficult to solve I found a solution
To solve the problem the `input` in **initialization** must be equal to `type="text"` and then change to `type="password"` with the first focus or insert input

```js
function changeTypeInput(inputElement){ 
  inputElement.type="password" 
}
```

```html
<input type="text"
  id="anyUniqueId"  
  onfocus="changeTypeInput(this)"
  oninput="changeTypeInput(this)"
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

it's relative to the browser
settings => automatic entry => password => Offer to save passwords (no)

Comment: this is not offer to save password; this is a select picker from password stored. I don't know if you understand the difference; this breaks into the Interface of a Web Page, and I see no way to deactivate it from the web page, since I don't have access to the browser settings of user.

Comment: The problem is that if the user uses a password selector (external or internal) you will not be able to block it

Comment: the selector is from the Google Chrome administrator ... but I can't find a way to disable the suggestions to choose password programmatically. I really feel that this feature, although good for ordinary pages, becomes intrusive when you want to do something different.